# The ability to execute current location information of the geolocator package in the background, which was working before, has ceased to function

Tags: flutter, dart, geolocator

I was executing the following code triggered by receiving FCM in the background using firebase_messaging.

```dart
Future<LatLng> fetchCurrentLocation() async {
  final currentLocation = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
  return LatLng(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude);
}
```

And, this was running without any issues, but it has stopped running since a little while ago. Specifically,

`final currentLocation = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();`

It stops at this point and the execution resumes when transitioning from the background to the foreground.

Since it was working before, it's puzzling why it's no longer working.

How can I make it work in the background as well?

`final currentLocation = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();`

Is it possible to make it run?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's relevant, but previously, when I wanted to retrieve the current location even in the background, setting breakpoints in debug mode in VSCode wouldn't cause it to stop during background execution. However, since it became unresponsive, breakpoints now cause it to stop when running in the background as well.